# Using geom_rect to shade graphs generated in loop

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to make graphs from multiple tab separated files in a folder. One graph for each file. The first column of these files is same. I also have to shade some regions in all the plots, the regions to shaded is same for all files. The coordinates for shading are in a different file. I can successfully make a graph from a single file with following code.

```
shading_cor<- read.table(file="shading", header=T, sep="\t") # importing shading cordinates
shading <- geom_rect(aes(NULL, NULL, xmin = start, xmax = end), ymin= -Inf, ymax=Inf, data=shading_cor, fill="grey80", alpha=0.2)
to_be_plotted <- read.table(file="plot_file", header=F, sep="\t") # one of the data files
ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data=melt(to_be_plotted, id = "V1", measure = c("V2", "V3")),  aes(V1, value, colour = variable)) +
  shading+theme_bw()
```

Now to make graphs in a loop, I am roughly using this syntax, which makes plots for each file. I know it is not the most efficient way, but serves my purpose as beginner.

```
my_files <- list.files(pattern=".txt") 
for (i in files){
  my_data  <- read.table(i, header=F )
  pdf(paste0(i,".pdf"))
  print (ggplot() + geom_line(data=melt(my_data, id = "V1", measure = c("V2", "V3")),  aes(V1, value, colour = variable)))
  dev.off
}
```

However to shade all the plots that that are made by above loop, I modify the code that follows

```
shading_cor <- read.table(file="shading", header=T, sep="\t") # importing shading cordinates
shading <- geom_rect(aes(NULL, NULL, xmin = start, xmax = end), ymin= -Inf, ymax=Inf, data=shading_cor, fill="grey80", alpha=0.2)
my_files <- list.files(pattern=".txt") 
for (i in files){
  my_data  <- read.table(i, header=F )
  pdf(paste0(i,".pdf"))
  p1 <- ggplot() + geom_line(data=my_data(graph, id = "V1", measure = c("V2", "V3")),  aes(V1, value, colour = variable)
  print (p1 + shading)
  dev.off
}`
```

loop following code results in to error:

> "arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 32 Calls: print ...
>   as.data.frame -> as.data.frame.list -> eval -> eval -> data.frame"

I have no idea what is wrong here. I am sure I must be making some very silly mistake. I will be grateful for a solution. 
EDIT - some test data

```
> dput(test1.txt)
structure(list(X20 = c(21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
29L, 30L), X0 = c(5L, 0L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 3L), X.5 = c(-2, 
0, -12, -5, -6, -5, -4, -4, -3, -2)), .Names = c("X20", "X0", 
"X.5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
> dput(test2.txt)
structure(list(X20 = c(21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
29L, 30L), X0 = c(5L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L), X.2 = c(-3L, 
0L, 0L, -4L, -3L, -3L, -2L, 0L, -3L, -2L)), .Names = c("X20", 
"X0", "X.2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
> dput(test3.txt)
structure(list(X20 = c(21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
29L, 30L), X0 = c(0L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L), X.2 = c(-3L, 
-3L, -3L, -4L, -3L, -2L, -2L, -1L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("X20", 
"X0", "X.2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

and the shading coordinated could be like

```
start  end
20     22
25     27
29     30
```

Comment: do you mean `print(p1 + shading)` ?

Comment: Yes. Sorry about that, just edited it.

Comment: can you post a sample of your data so I can reproduce your problem? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610

Comment: @mts Thanks, pasting first 10 rows of two files. I am not sure if this is what you wanted.

Comment: The code to shut off the open graphics device normally uses parens at the end, as in `dev.off()` instead of `dev.off`. Does that change affect your problem?

Comment: @Amit please use the `dput` function as described in the link I posted here before.